# GIT bash as Terminal not working in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash

For home office I need to setup a whole bunch of things, however I seem to keep running into issues with making git bash work properly in VSCode.
I have installed Git 64-bit Git for Windows.

Initially it didn't work at all until I added the following to my settings.json

```
"terminal.external.windowsExec": "D:\\SOFTWARE\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "D:\\SOFTWARE\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

with the second line saying it is deprecated, but it works none-the-less.

Now it runs but inconsistently. Running just the 'ls' command repeatedly it :

- 45% of the time won't run
- 45% of the time states 'segmentation fault'
- 10% actually work

The git bash app itself runs the commands with zero issues. I have read up multiple posts on 'segmentation fault' and seem no closer to the issue.

What I have tried :

- Adding exceptions to AV (only running defender ATM)
- re-installing git multiple times with admin rights to main and secondary drives
- Win10 safe-mode installation
- restarts before and after installations and installs
- installing older versions of Git.
- adding '*\Git\bin' to environment variables

I am really at a loss here and it works fine at the office. Perhaps I am missing something obvious.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I needed.
I needed to add in the settings.json file the following code :

```
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
        "PATH" : "D:\\SOFTWARE\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
    }
```

Having done that I thought I could remove the previous deprecated code :

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "D:\\SOFTWARE\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

But it seems it still was required.

I hope this helps someone as most of the references out there (that I could find) refers to the older deprecated code.

Note : seems now my 'vagrant' and 'npm' command wont run at all anymore